# Solved ReactJS+Redux this.props.action is not a function

Tags: reactjs, redux

SOLVED:

I solved it by erasing 'export' in Dashboard component and erasing the {} keys in App.js (where Dashboard is called). Thanks for helping me :)

Hi I'm a newbie on react+redux and as the title says I'm trying to connect action function to Component but I get

TypeError: this.props.dashBrd is not a function

Here's the code

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import {dashBrd}  from "../../actions/dashboard";

export class Dashboard extends Component {

  static propTypes = {
    dashboard: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    dashBrd: PropTypes.func.isRequired
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.dashBrd();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <h2>Dashboard</h2>
        <table className="table table-striped">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Id</th>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Price</th>
              <th>Stock</th>
              <th />
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody></tbody>
        </table>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  dashboard: state.dashboard
});
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { dashBrd })(Dashboard);
```

and the action is in other file

```
import axios from "axios";
import { GET_DASHBOARD } from "./types";
import { createMessage, returnError } from "./messages";
import { tokenConfig } from "./auth";

export const dashBrd= () => (dispatch) => {
  const token = JSON.stringify({ jwt: tokenConfig() });
  //Headers
  const config = {
    headers: {
      "Content-type": "application/json"
    }
  };
  axios
    .get("http://localhost:8080/dashboard", config, token)
    .then(res => {
      dispatch(createMessage("Success!"));
      dispatch({
        type: GET_DASHBOARD,
        payload: res.data
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
      dispatch(returnError(err.data,400));

    });
};
```

I've tried almost everything, exporting, importing... But in the file shows it as imported, but not passed to the props of Dashboard

EDIT: This code is for register page, that is actually working good.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { register } from "../../actions/auth";
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
class Register extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    register: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    isAuthenticated: PropTypes.bool
  };
  state = {
    email: "",
    password: ""
  };

  onChange = e => this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });

  onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { email, password } = this.state;
    this.props.register(email, password);
    this.setState({
      email: " ",
      password: " "
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { email, password } = this.state;
    if (this.props.isAuthenticated) {
      return <Redirect to="/dashboard" />;
    }
    return (
      <div className="loginBody">
        <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
          <h2 style={{ color: "white" }}>Registro</h2>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label style={{ color: "white" }}>Email</label>
            <input
              className="form-control"
              type="email"
              name="email"
              onChange={this.onChange}
              value={email}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label style={{ color: "white" }}>Password</label>

            <input
              className="form-control"
              type="password"
              name="password"
              onChange={this.onChange}
              value={password}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="form-group"></div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <button type="submit" className="btnLogin">
              Enviar
            </button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }

}
const mapStateToProps = state =>({
  isAuthenticated: state.auth.isAuthenticated
})
export default connect(mapStateToProps,{register})(Register);
```

register action

```
export const register = (email, password) => dispatch => {
  //Headers
  const config = {
    headers: {
      "Content-type": "application/json"
    }
  };
  //Request body
  const body = JSON.stringify({ email, password: password });
  axios
    .post("http://localhost:8080/register", body, config)
    .then(res => {
      dispatch({
        type: REGISTER_SUCCESS,
        payload: res.data
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      dispatch(returnError(err.response.data, err.response.status));
      dispatch({
        type: REGISTER_FAIL
      });
    });
};
```

Comment: `dispatch` is only available in a connected component.
Your action file is not a connected component.

Comment: Have a look at this : https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch

Comment: Hi thanks for answer, I'm trying to pass through HOC the props for it at the end of the first block of codes, anyways I did the same for register and login page, with their respectives actions and dispatchers and they work. But with this file doesn't. I've read that page to verify it and It should work :(

Comment: Can you add the code for either the login or reister page for which it is working?

Comment: Please add code for `register` action file as well, that is the real deal :P

Comment: haha sorry I forgot it

Comment: It should work, did you try consoling all the props which you are passing through your `HOC`

Comment: Yes I did, but it does not shows neither dashboard or dashBrd()

Comment: It does not show the `keys` or the value is undefined ?

Comment: Nothing :(. The editor recognize  the dashBrd function but when I try to pass it in the connect function is like the props aren't mapped

Answer (score 0):

The following code shoud works

```
import axios from "axios";
import { GET_DASHBOARD } from "./types";
import { createMessage, returnError } from "./messages";
import { tokenConfig } from "./auth";

export const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  dashBrd: () => {
    const token = JSON.stringify({ jwt: tokenConfig() });
    //Headers
    const config = {
      headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/json"
      }
    };
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:8080/dashboard", config, token)
      .then(res => {
        dispatch(createMessage("Success!"));
        dispatch({
          type: GET_DASHBOARD,
          payload: res.data
        });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        dispatch(returnError(err.data, 400));

      });
  }
})
```

And your component

`import {mapDispatchToProps}  from "../../actions/dashboard";`

And the last line

`export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Dashboard);`

You can rename the variable to whatever you want.
Hope this helps.

I prefer the way that put mapStateToProps, `export defaut connect...` in to the same file as `mapDispatchToProps`, it's easier to read.

Comment: Do I have something to change in Dashboard componentDidMount??. It says the same :(

Comment: No, you just need to update the last line `export default connect`, can you console.log(this.props) on componentDidMount?

Comment: Failed prop type: The prop `dashboard` is marked as required in `Dashboard`, but its value is `undefined`. and the same for dashBrd function

Comment: temporary comment out the line `dashboard: PropTypes.array.isRequired,` and see does it works

Comment: It says undefined, it's like the props aren't passing through HOC

Comment: Which value is undefined? `dashboard ` or `dashBrd `

Comment: Neither dashboard and dashBrd aren't passing